# Change the way hibernate looks up related data?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have the following "parent" pojo...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")  
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parent")
    List<Child> children;
}
```

and I have the following child POJO :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

The result of this will be that I have two tables, and my jpa repository will perform queries using the parent_id field within the child table.

However, What if I want it be like a lookup, where by there is a third table for the relationship, where I have the child id and the parent id as a row, and that would be the relationship? can I modify my spring - jpa / hibernate setup for that? If so, some help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you looking to gain by having a third table that your current set up cannot handle?

Comment: @roger I need to be able to handle this lookup scenario because this system is replacing an old one, and I have to be able to handle migrating data from this lookup, pending client spec confirmation, the new system may also keep this structure. I would prefer to use the foreign key lookup that is standard, but alas, it ain't up to me. :(

Comment: You're looking for `@JoinTable`.